# LINQ: How to convert the nested hierarchical object to flatten object

Tags: linq

How to convert the nested hierarchical object to flatten objects by using LINQ? I know that we can easily use foreach loop to achieve that. But I'm wondering if there is a way to write it in LINQ.

```
class Person{
   public int ID {get;set}
   public string Name {get;set}
   public List<Person> Children {get;}
}
```

**Data :**

```
ID   : 1

Name : Jack

Children

2 | Rose 

3 | Paul
```

I like to convert this data into flatten format like below.

```
1 | Jack 

2 | Rose 

3 | Paul
```

How can we do it with Linq?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want it to flatten an arbitrarily deep tree of people, I suggest the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetFamily(Person parent)
{
    yield return parent;
    foreach (Person child in parent.Children) // check null if you must
        foreach (Person relative in GetFamily(child))
            yield return relative;
}
```

There isn't really any good way to shorten this with LINQ, because anonymous lambdas can't call themselves recursively without implementing Y.  You could "reduce" the above method to

```
return parent.Children.SelectMany(p => GetFamily(p))
                      .Concat(new Person[] { parent });
```

or alternatively

```
yield return parent;
    foreach (Person relative in parent.Children.SelectMany(GetFamily))
        yield return relative;
```

but that seems sort of unnecessary to me.

Comment: Of course lambdas can call themselves. Here's Fibonacci using a recursive lambda: `Func<int, int> fib = null; fib = i => i <= 1 ? i : fib(i-1) + fib(i-2);`

Comment: I said "*anonymous* lambdas can't call themselves", which is why he can't write a single expression that returns the value he wants -- he needs to declare a named function to recurse with.

Comment: So by putting something anonymous in a variable it is no longer anonymous? E.g. `var a = new { X = 5 };`? I'd still call what `a` references an anonymous type. Microsoft unconditionally says that ["A lambda expression is an anonymous function"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and look at the second example of [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx). Almost everything anonymous has to be put in some kind of named variable or parameter; otherwise they're not usable by code. That doesn't mean they're not anonymous.

Comment: I'm going to keep using the word "anonymous" to mean "not identified by name."  In your example, the type is anonymous, but the object is not anonymous.

Comment: All objects are anonymous. Objects do not have names, types do. Object references may be placed inside a named variable, but the name is of the variable, not the object. Example `var alice = new object(); var bob = alice;` - is the object "named" `alice` or `bob`, or both? Neither - its reference is simply contained within two variables named `alice` and `bob`. It's the same with methods. They can either be defined either in a class where a name must be given, or as an anonymous method or lambda where a name will be generated by the compiler and remain anonymous in code.

Comment: Also take care to differentiate between a method and a delegate. `Action a = () => { }` is a syntactic sugar for `Action a = new Action(() => { });`. Notice that the variable `a` does not hold a method, but rather an instance of a delegate of type `Action` that points to the lambda. So even if you claimed that assigning an object to a variable makes the object non-anonymous, you be "assigning a name" to a delegate, not a method. The method remains untouched since it's a static construct in an assembly, not something that can be "named" at runtime.

Comment: You're just using words in a way that I don't think is common parlance.  I appeal to the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function *"In programming language theory, an anonymous function (also function constant, function literal, or lambda function) is a function (or a subroutine) defined, and possibly called, without being bound to an identifier."*  Saying "objects do not have names" is not how I care to use the word "name", so we will remain in disagreement about that.

Answer (score 8):

This is a nice, generic and reusable extension method:

```
static public IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> descendBy)
{
    if (!source.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        foreach (T value in source)
        {
            yield return value;

            if (!descendBy(value).IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                foreach (T child in descendBy(value).Descendants<T>(descendBy))
                {
                    yield return child;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above, use like this:

```
var allChildren = parent.Children.Descendants(p => p.Children);
```

One minor nit is that it doesn't include the original parent in the list, you'll need to do that.