# LINQ query to navigate an object hierachy

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have an object graph of Countries / States / Cities, like below:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public List<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a simple way to query a `List<Country>` to get all the cities?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/ ... the SelectMany() method will do it for you.

Comment: Or search SO for "selectmany" or for "flatten linq".

Comment: okay.. my q is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938409/linq-how-to-convert-the-nested-hierarchical-object-to-flatten-object
I'm happy for this to be closed.. what's the protocol, do I just delete it?

Comment: Leave it for now - it'll get closed eventually.

Comment: That's not really a dup. The question you found is for a parent-child hierarchy which isn't quite the same as what you posed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `countryList.SelectMany(c => c.States).SelectMany(s => s.Cities)`?

Or maybe this?

```
var cities = from country in countryList
             from state in country.States
             from city in state.Cities
             select city;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be simpler! :-)

```
var cities = from country in countries //List<Country>
             from state in country.States
             from city in state.Cities
             select city.Name;
```