# Iterate over a list that contains a self-referencing list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, collections

Lets say I have following database model:
[image: Database model]

In code this looks like this:

**ButtonCategories**

```
public class ButtonCategory
{
    public ButtonCategory()
    {
        this.Buttons = new HashSet<Button>();
        this.SubCategories = new HashSet<ButtonCategory>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
    public virtual ButtonCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ButtonCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
}
```

**Buttons**

```
public class Button
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ButtonCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ButtonCategoryId")]
    public virtual ButtonCategory ButtonCategory { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, my **ButtonCategories** has a self-referencing list.

The problem that occured, is that I want to convert all **ButtonCategories** to another type, let us say **ButtonCategoriesMock**. And I want to do the same for all the **Buttons** in the lists.
The problem to do this is that I do not know, and neither can say, how many sub levels there are. It is possible that there is only one sub category, but also that it is a sub category of a sub category of a sub category,... and so on.

[image: Example]

How can I easily convert all the **ButtonCategory** items and **Button** items to another type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to flatten the output, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938409/linq-how-to-convert-the-nested-hierarchical-object-to-flatten-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about 'easily' but you can implement your own recursive extension methods to do this:

However, I believe a Traverse method, and select might handle your situation

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> fnRecurse)
    {
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            yield return item;

            IEnumerable<T> seqRecurse = fnRecurse(item);

            if (seqRecurse != null)
            {
                foreach (T itemRecurse in Traverse(seqRecurse, fnRecurse))
                {
                    yield return itemRecurse;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Snippet available at: [LINQ and recursive functions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3d441d-1e49-4855-8ae8-60068b3ef741/linq-and-recursive-functions)

See:

- [Using LINQ to Objects for recursion](http://blog.mutable.net/post/2008/05/23/using-linq-to-objects-for-recursion.aspx)
- [Recursive Select in C# and LINQ](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/recursive-select-in-c-sharp-and-linq.aspx)
- [Recursively Traversing a Hierarchical Data Structure Using LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68978/Recursively-Traversing-a-Hierarchical-Data-Structu)