# Flatten or Map objects in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to create generic class that will map or flatten an object.
Lets say i have this 2 classes

```
public class Description
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int WordsCount { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public List<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
}
```

I try to create something like this:

```
Item item = new Item()
    {
        Url = "http",
        Title = "home page",
        Details = new Description() { Info = "some info" },
        WordsCount = 220,
        Headers = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" },
        Descriptions = new List<Descriptions>() 
            {
                new Description() { Info = "info 1" },
                new Description() { Info = "info 2" },
                new Description() { Info = "info 3" },
            }
    };
```

After the flattening/mapping i want to have something like:

```
Item {
   Url: 'http',
   Title: 'home page',
   Details.Info: 'some info',
   WordsCount: '220',
   Headers: 'One^Two^Three',
   Descriptions.0.Info: 'info 1'.
   Descriptions.1.Info: 'info 2',
   Descriptions.2.Info: 'info 3',
 }
```

I tried with AutoMapper but i guess i am not able to achieve this
Any suggestions?

Comment: public User Owner { get; set; } this means to be public Description Details {get; set;}

Comment: Isn't it a better idea to have the `Item` class do this by itself?
Since it looks like it's the `Item` class that has a list of `Description`?

Comment: I am trying to illustrate an example, Item can have list of many other classes

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938409/linq-how-to-convert-the-nested-hierarchical-object-to-flatten-object?rq=1

Comment: In that case i doubt you're going to manage staying away from abstract classes and interfaces since you will have to guarantee a specific kind of behavior from the "flatten"-able classes