# Asp.Net Mvc hierarchical categories self-related with One-To-Many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create category tree. With this purpose i created some classes. I done somethings let me show you what i did and whats gone wrong.

I created a self-referenced model like below.

```
public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category RootCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

and i mapped it like below

```
public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);
        this.Property(t => t.Published)
            .IsRequired();
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Category");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        this.Property(t => t.Published).HasColumnName("Published");
        HasOptional(x => x.RootCategory).WithMany(x => x.SubCategories).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

To Create and Edit Category i created a ViewModel like below

```
public class CreateEditCategoryViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }

    private int? _selectedCategory;
    public int? SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedCategory; }
        set { _selectedCategory = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller Create action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateEditCategoryViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Category category = new Category();

            if (viewModel.SelectedCategory > 0)
            {
                category.ParentId = viewModel.SelectedCategory;
            }

            category.Title = viewModel.Title;
            category.Published = viewModel.Published;

            db.Categories.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        ViewBag.SelectedCategory = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Title", viewModel.SelectedCategory);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Here is my Create view,

```
    @model BiSahne.Areas.Administrator.Models.CreateEditCategoryViewModel

<div id="inputs" class="box g8">
    <h2 class="box-ttl">Category Ekle</h2>
    <div class="box-body form">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "label input g4" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "g12" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)

        <span class="label g4">Published</span>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Published, new { @class = "g1" })

        <button type="submit" class="green btn-m flt-r g3">Kaydet</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box coll g8" style="height: 500px">
    <div class="box-body form">
        <span class="label g16">Categories</span>
        <hr />
        <select size="20" title="Select Category" name="SelectedCategory" class="form-control select" data-live-search="true">

            @foreach (BiSahne.Models.Content.Category item in ViewBag.SelectedCategory)
            {

                if (item.RootCategory == null) //top level
                {
                    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Title</option>

                    foreach (var item2 in item.SubCategories)
                    {
                        <option value="@item2.Id">---@item2.Title</option>
                        if (item2.SubCategories.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var item3 in item2.SubCategories)
                            {
                                <option value="@item3.Id">------@item3.Title</option>
                                if (item3.SubCategories.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item4 in item3.SubCategories)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item4.Id">------@item4.Title</option>
                                        if (item4.SubCategories.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var item5 in item4.SubCategories)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@item5.Id">------@item5.Title</option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

}

This is my Edit action method.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);

        if (category == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        CreateEditCategoryViewModel viewModel = new CreateEditCategoryViewModel()
        {
            Id = category.Id,
            Title = category.Title,
            Published = category.Published,
        };


        ViewBag.SelectedCategory = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Title", viewModel.SelectedCategory);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

> Edit.cshtml view same as Create.cshtml view above.

I can create category and i can assign a parent for it. But when i'm trying to edit the category -and also when Create Action returns view due to ModelState is not valid- i'm getting error like below

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to 'BiSahne.Models.Content.Category'
```

Pointed to this line in edit.cshtml

```
                @foreach (BiSahne.Models.Content.Category item in ViewBag.SelectedCategory)
            {
```

How can i fix that problem? I have to list categories and select the selected category.

Comment: `ViewBag.SelectedCategory` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not `IEnumerable<Caregory>`

Comment: Can you figure out how can i do the hierarchical list with using Html.Listbox?

Comment: Not sure why you doing this (and it will all fail unless you have exactly 4 levels deep anyway). You can create an extension method to flatten your hierarchical `Category` to a flat list in the controller and then create a new `SelectList` from that for use in the view

Comment: I'm doing this because i cant do it with model bind. In fuct im not experienced coder. trying to understand how things works.

Actually my problem is simple as use 
`Html.ListBox(model => model.SelectedCategory, ViewBag.SelectedCategory as SelectList, new { class = "g12"" })`

But, i completely have no idea how to do hierarchy here.

Comment: Firstly you cannot name the `ViewBag` property the same as the model property. And you can and should bind to your model property. You need to translate the hierarchical structure to a flat list which you can do with a linq extension method. And you might be interested in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768069/MVC-Custom-Select-Control)

Comment: Article seems good start point. Thank you very much.

Comment: A few examples of methods to flatten a hierarchical structure [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938409/linq-how-to-convert-the-nested-hierarchical-object-to-flatten-object)